# Check if array param is not null in SQLDelight (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, sqldelight

I've tested that select with PostgreSQL and it seems to work fine - return a list of items with resourceId mentioned in `:resourceIdList` (if any). If `:resourceIdList` is null - then return all of them.

```
select b.resourceid,
       b.datecreatedutc as basecreated,
       b.datedeletedutc as basedeleted
from productbasetable b
where b.datedeletedutc is null
  and case
          when :resourceIdList is not null
              then b.resourceid in :resourceIdList
          else true
    end;
```

The problem occurs when I'm trying to use it in **SqlDelight**: the generated code has a problem with `when :resourceIdList is not null` (`encode` fun expects a T type, not a List)
[image]

Is there another way to check if `:resourceIdList` is null/empty before the `IN` statement?

Comment: as to your SQL, you can simplify it to `where b.datedeletedutc is null and (:resourceIdList is not null or b.resourceid in :resourceIdList)`. But this won't solve the issue, it seems like a SQLDelight bug, I suggest you filling an issue or asking a question on [github](https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/issues/new/choose)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov yeah, I've created an issue, but don't expect any solution soon. They have tons of them open :( it's here: https://github.com/AlecStrong/sql-psi/issues/285

Comment: Yep, some of them are mine as well :D The only solution I can think of at this point is to create two functions instead of one